# How can I get into control panel without Admin privileges

Tags: administrator, control-panel

I made an admin account on my computer but can't remember the password. now i can't get into my control panel.

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator account, see my answer on how to do that, using the Administrator account change the password to your existing admin account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XP contains a backdoor entrance to administrator control. The following will only work if the previous owner didn't know enough to close the backdoor.

First, boot into Safe Mode: Start your PC, and press F5 before the Windows logo appears. (It may take a few tries to get the timing right.) From the resulting Boot menu, select Safe Mode. When the logon screen appears, it will probably contain a user you've never seen before, Administrator, that does not have a password. Thus, you can enter Windows as an administrator-level user.

Once inside Windows, you can use Control Panel's User Accounts applet to change the password on the other administrator account or create a new one for yourself. And while you're there, you might also want to add a password to the Administrator account in order to close the backdoor. But that's probably the case.

Link Taken From:
http://www.pcworld.com/article/206809/admin_no_password.html

Comment: Which kind of safe mode? SM w/ cmd?

Comment: Just Safe Mode not with command

Comment: Thx, helped alot, back online again.

Comment: How?, I pressed the tick.

Comment: Yes it's closed now